# Object programming issue

Tags: python, list, function, class

I'm trying to solve this exercise. My desired output is to print the dictionary with the values; name of "Trasa" and list of every Warszawa1 Warszawa 2 etc. For this I created the second function : `stat_info`. Current output: `{'Name and information': ['Ko', <function station.stat_info at 0x7fe4dbbe3040>]}` Desired output : `{'Name and information': ['Ko',[Warszawa1, Warszawa 2 etc.]`
My code:

```
class station:
    def __init__(self, name, possibility_of_change, time_of_stay):
        self.name = name
        self.possibility_of_change = possibility_of_change
        self.time_of_stay = time_of_stay
        stat = []
        stat.append(self.name)
        self.stat = stat

    def stat_info(self):
        return self.stat



class Position_of_route:
    def __init__(self, station, time_between_2_stays):
        self.station = station
        self.time_between_2_stays = time_between_2_stays


class Route(station):
    def __init__(self, name1, list_of_positions):
        self.name1 = name1
        self.list_of_postitions = list_of_positions
    
    def trasa_info(self):
        return 5


    def generate(self, time):
        przystanki = [
            station("Warszawa1",True,3),
            station("Warszawa2",True,5),
            station("Warszawa3",False,0),
            station("Warszawa4",True,3),
            station("Warszawa5",True,7),
            station("Warszawa6",True,3),
            station("Warszawa7",True,9),
            station("Warszawa8",False,0),
            station("Warszawa9",True,12),
        ]
        a={
            "Name and information": [self.name1,station.stat_info]

        }
        return a
        
print(Route("Ko",[1,2]).generate(18))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the `station.stat_info` function but just storing its reference.  In any case, this is a class method, and what you will need to call is the equivalent instance method using the instances of `station` which you have, which are stored on the `przystanki` list.  For example:

```
a = { "Name and information": [self.name1,
                              [przystanek.stat_info() for przystanek in przystanki]] }
```

In this example, you would get a list of lists at the relevant place inside your data structure:

```
{'Name and information': ['Ko', [['Warszawa1'], ['Warszawa2'], ['Warszawa3'], ['Warszawa4'], ['Warszawa5'], ['Warszawa6'], ['Warszawa7'], ['Warszawa8'], ['Warszawa9']]]}
```

The question is a little ambiguous as to the exact output format required, and the calling code may differ if you wish to join together the lists, for example:

```
        info = []
        for przystanek in przystanki:
            info.extend(przystanek.stat_info())
        a = {                        
            "Name and information": [self.name1, info]
        }
```

if you wanted instead to have:

```
{'Name and information': ['Ko', ['Warszawa1', 'Warszawa2', 'Warszawa3', 'Warszawa4', 'Warszawa5', 'Warszawa6', 'Warszawa7', 'Warszawa8', 'Warszawa9']]}
```

but in any case you will be calling these instance methods.

---

*Note on variable names: `przystanki` means "stations" in Polish, so I chose `przystanek` (meaning "station" singular) for the loop variable.*

Comment: @Kokin what error did you see? (Note that the code shown here will need to be put in place of your existing `a={ .... }`, suitably indented.)

Comment: Meanwhile, I corrected the name of przystanki and it is why it doesn't work. Sorry for wasting your time, your solution was really tricky and great :)

Comment: @Kokin Okay, so is it working for you now?

Comment: Can I ask you about one thing. Similar question, connected with objects. Can I ask you for contact?

Comment: @Kokin If you have another question, please post it to this site as a new question. There are many other people who can help to answer it if I don't see it myself.

Comment: Really good idea. I tried your solution one more time. Really sorry but I thought it will give me enough information to solve it. I tried to return the information "The route contains of Warszawa1, Warszawa2, etc. Now I got {'Name and information': ['Ko', ["The route contains of stations:['Warszawa1']", "The route contains of stations:['Warszawa2']", "The route contains of stations:['Warszawa3']", "The route contains of stations:['Warszawa4']", "The route contains of stations:['Warszawa5'] etc. My code is:    def stat_info(self):
        return f'The route contains of stations:{self.stat}'